# Sum of characters modulo k

Tags: number-theory, characters

I want to find $\sum_{n \leq x} \chi(n) $, where $\chi$ is a non-principal character modulo $k$. I am trying to find $\sum_{n \leq x} \chi (n) n$ using Abel's summation formula, where the series $a_n = \chi(n)$.

Comment: What is character modulo k? Do you mean number modulo k?

Comment: A character of an abelian group $G$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}*$. If this group is the group of invertible congruence classes modulo $k$ forsome positive integer $k$, we call $\chi$ a character mod $k$.

Comment: To have a closed formula for such a sum would be a dream for any number theoretician looking for an unconditional improvement for the size of the least quadratic non-residue. Such a sum can be bounded through Polya-Vinogradov inequality and Burgess' bound, however.

Comment: Are you aware that $\sum_{n \leq k} \chi(n) =0$ (hence the sum is periodic)?

Comment: If I'm right, you should find something like that in Serre, 'A course in arithmetic'. The chapter about the Dirichlet's theorem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can find several results on this sum with a Dirichlet character modulo $k$ in Tom Apostol's book on analytic number theory. In fact, $\sum_{n=1}^k\chi(n)=0$, so that the sum is periodic. For non-principal Dirichlet characters modulo $k$ we have the estimate of Polya
$$
\left|\sum_{n\le x} \chi(n) \right|\le \sqrt{k}\log(k).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, what I needed was an asymptotic formula for the above sum. With this result, it becomes very evident.